# Connecting cables when end point rotates 360

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, cables

I need to be able to rotate raspi camera 360' by motor and up/down by servo. The problem is that when I rotate it 360', all camera cables will tangle up. What is the method to make it right? I need camera, servo and lighting cables to go through that motor.

Comment: By 360 do you mean you could turn it multiple times around, or real 360° so that if you want to turn 5° "more" you need to turn backwards 355°? In the first case no cables, in the latter case longer cables often suffice.

Comment: All around unlimited number of times. Like in tank. I need it also for sonic radar.

Comment: How much total wattage are you hoping to transfer and is data going in both directions? Also what data rates?

Comment: It's for low power servos and motors... for RC boat.

Comment: can't you use a rotating mirror or other optical steering, and keep the camera mounting fixed?

Comment: interesting solution, but still need that for radar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- A slip ring (or multiples for each cable). Advantages are that you can easily run mostly the same signals signals as over your cables. Disadvantage is that it has contact wear and isn't suited for high rotation speeds due to that.

  Example: [image]
- Rotary transformers (again one for each cable) like in VCR heads. You can only use AC signals here, it is more complicated to build, but you can do it in higher speeds.
  Example: [image]

Comment: Nice photos! Where is the slip ring installation?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: It is from the radiotelescope astropeiler. It is my favorite wikipedia image for slip rings; I always show it t people who say that slip rings are only good for a few connections but they need more and of better quality. Those are quite a few and they seem to be good enough for a radio telescope...

Comment: They are all accessible for service and, I'd guess, cleaned daily. You can afford a service schedule for a telescope that would be uneconomic in many other applications. Still, nice!

Comment: You can buy slip rings intended for low power DC applications on eBay relatively cheaply.

Comment: @NickJohnson: You can buy lots of things on ebay relatively cheaply... like 4000mAh 18650 batteries...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Unlike those, these actually perform as advertised. At least, the ones I've used did.

Comment: thanx, I think that having the name of it, answers my question :) I'll find proper ones. I am accepting this.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I wish the slip rings in our plant looked like that, but they only get cleaned maybe yearly... Still they work, without issues.  I've got one stack here that has 46 connections, varying from a 50HP AC motor down to it's encoder, no issues.  We also pass a communications link at 480kbps through them no problem.  Big trick is multiple brushes per ring, so even if one is dirty, the other conducts.  Oh, we run up to about 300 RPM on the slip rings, but they can go higher.

Comment: That is really cool. I will have to send that around at work - we usually only see dirty, crufty slip-rings in generators.